# Image Upload in Silverlight Application

Tags: c#, file-upload, filestream, silverlight-5.0, fileinfo

When I am trying to upload an image from my local drive to ms sql using Silverlight Application, it is throwing an exception "**File operation not permitted. Access to path 'userimage.png' is denied**". How to solve this? I am not good in Silverlight. Please Help me.

My Code is,

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.ShowDialog();
string filename = ofd.File.Name;
FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(filename);
long numBytes = fInfo.Length;
FileStream fStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream);
byte[] data = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
```

I am getting the error here, "`FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(filename);`"

And Stack Trace is,

> at System.IO.FileSecurityState.EnsureState()
>      at System.IO.FileInfo.Init(String fileName, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.FileInfo..ctor(String fileName)
>      at AttendanceManagementSystem.InsertPopup.btnimg_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
>      at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
>      at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
>      at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)

Comment: Which OS and which browser do you use? Did you set / added custom permissions? Did you read the msnd usage guideline to the odf (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221415(v=vs.95).aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it is working fine now. The working code is given below.

```
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png";
            bool? userClickedOK = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (userClickedOK == true)
            {
                System.IO.Stream fileStream = ofd.File.OpenRead();
                FileStream fStream = ofd.File.OpenRead();
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream);
                byte[] imagedata = br.ReadBytes((int)fStream.Length);
            }
```

Now the byte array "`imagedata`" can insert to db.